# Hydra Password Cracker error using cygwin64 in windows

Tags: web, passwords, cygwin, hydra

Please Help i cannot install hydra password cracker using cygwin64 in windows 8.1 What should i do
Below are pics
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od5yl.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oye7v.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGwhM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT post link to images. Copy and paste the relevant part of the error.

You are missing `windres`, so you need the package that contains it.
To look for it, use `cygcheck`

assuming you want to compile for Cygwin:

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/bin/windres
Found 6 matches for usr/bin/windres
binutils-debuginfo-2.35.1-1 - binutils-debuginfo: Debug info for binutils
...
binutils-2.36.1-2 - binutils: GNU assembler, linker, and similar utilities
```

Install `binutils`
If instead you want to compile for Mingw64, you need the similar package.

```
$ cygcheck -l mingw64-x86_64-binutils | grep windres
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe
```

Are you sure to have the proper compiler installed ? `binutils` is a requirement of any compiler.

Comment: I am not sure the proper compiler installed

Comment: I will done following procedure you have told me and i will reply you soon

Comment: So i first delete the entire cygwin folder and install cygwin again but now i get the following error after running Cygwin Terminal.
"bash is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file"
What to do now ?

Comment: your AV is swalling your installation ? Rerun setup and re-install the `bash` package

Comment: Oh thanks it works now  after typing your command i get this

Comment: furqan@furqan-PC ~
$ cygcheck -p usr/bin/windres
Found 6 matches for usr/bin/windres
binutils-debuginfo-2.35.1-1 - binutils-deb
binutils-debuginfo-2.35.2-1 - binutils-deb
binutils-debuginfo-2.36.1-2 - binutils-deb
binutils-2.35.1-1 - binutils: GNU assemble
binutils-2.35.2-1 - binutils: GNU assemble
binutils-2.36.1-2 - binutils: GNU assemble

Comment: furqan@furqan-PC ~
$ cygcheck =1 wingw64 x86 64=binutils | gr
-windres.exe
cygcheck: could not find '=1'

cygcheck: could not find 'wingw64'

cygcheck: could not find 'x86'

cygcheck: could not find '64=binutils'

Comment: Letter l not number 1, see `cygcheck --help` for details

Comment: furqan@furqan-PC ~
$ cygcheck -l mingw64-x86_64-binutils | grep
2-windres.exe
grep: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Now what can i do how do install windres

Comment: Use cygwin setup to install `binutils` or  `mingw64-x86_64-binutils` depending how you want to build the program.

Comment: Ok i have downloaded and install binutils and mingw64-x86_64-binutils.Now can it solve my windres problem.
I apologize for so many questions because i am beginner user.

Comment: Thanks man it works you are a real genius and time saver thanks for the Help.After installing binutils and mingw64-x86 my problem is solved.Thanks again

Comment: Please don't answer questions which are unsuitable for Stack Overflow as posed. Instead, vote to close the question as being in need of revision by the author. Only post an answer once that revision has occurred.